# Why is this sequence a [n] unable to correctly find its general term formula?

Tags: difference-equations

Given the sequence a [n], a [n] represents the general term of the sequence. Known conditions include:

```
a[n + 1] == a[n] + Log[n/(n + 1)], a[1] == 1
```

The result obtained from this is:

[image]

```
ClearAll["`*"]
RSolve[{a[n + 1] == a[n] + Log[n/(n + 1)], a[1] == 1}, a[n], 
  n] // FullSimplify
```

How to obtain the correct answer：

```
a[n] == 1 - Log[n]
```

Comment: Both expressions give the same sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done as follows.

```
FunctionExpand[Log[n/(n + 1)], Assumptions -> n \[Element] PositiveIntegers]
```

> `Log[n] - Log[1 + n]`

```
RSolve[{a[n + 1] == a[n] + Log[n] - Log[(n + 1)], a[1] == 1}, a[n], n]
```

> `{{a[n] -> 1 - Log[n]}}`

Comment: Or by `FunctionExpand[
 1 + Derivative[1, 0][Zeta][0, n] - Derivative[1, 0][Zeta][0, 1 + n], 
 Assumptions -> n \[Element] PositiveIntegers]` which results in `1+Log[Gamma[n]]-Log[Gamma[1+n]]`.
`

Comment: +1 Or put the `FunctionExpand` inside, e.g., `RSolve[{a[n + 1] == a[n] + Log[n/(n + 1)] // FunctionExpand, a[1] == 1}, a[n], n]`